# python XML to CSV Parse result non

Tags: python, xml, csv

i have this xml but having issue parsing it into csv, i tried simple print statement but still getting no value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>1820</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>2016-05-17T11:56:12</CreDtTm>
            <NbOfTxs>197</NbOfTxs>
            <CtrlSum>136661.81</CtrlSum>
            <InitgPty>
                <Nm>GS Netherlands CDZ C.V.</Nm>
            </InitgPty>
        </GrpHdr>
    </CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
    <CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
        <GrpHdr>
            <CreDtTm>2016-05-18T10:34:51</CreDtTm>
            <NbOfTxs>1</NbOfTxs>
            <CtrlSum>758.99</CtrlSum>
            <InitgPty>
                <Nm>GS Netherlands CDZ C.V.</Nm>
            </InitgPty></GrpHdr></CstmrDrctDbtInitn>
</Document>
```

and i want to iterate value for each node.

So far i have written code as below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv
with open("D:\Python\Dave\\17_05_16_1820_DD201606B10_Base.xml") as myFile:
    tree = ET.parse(myFile)
ns = {'d': 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02'}
# open a file for writing
Resident_data = open('Bank.csv', 'w')
# create the csv writer object
csvwriter = csv.writer(Resident_data)
resident_head = []

#write Header
MsgId = 'MsgId'
resident_head.append(MsgId)
CreDtTm = 'CreDtTm'
resident_head.append(CreDtTm)
NbOfTxs = 'NbOfTxs'
resident_head.append(NbOfTxs)
CtrlSum = 'CtrlSum'
resident_head.append(CtrlSum)
csvwriter.writerow(resident_head)

for member in tree.findall('.//d:Document/d:CstmrDrctDbtInitn/d:GrpHdr/d:MsgId', ns):
    resident = []
#write values
    MsgId = member.find('MsgId').text
    resident.append(MsgId)
    CreDtTm = member.find('CreDtTm').text
    resident.append(CreDtTm)
    NbOfTxs = member.find('NbOfTxs').text
    resident.append(NbOfTxs)
    CtrlSum = member.find('CtrlSum').text
    resident.append(CtrlSum)
    csvwriter.writerow(resident)
Resident_data.close()
```

I get no error and my Bank.csv has only header but no data please help

Comment: Put a `print` statement in the `for` loop, to be sure you have `member`s

Comment: Hi, I added print statement but get no result.

Comment: Means your `tree.findall` returned nothing. You should do some review

Comment: do you think the ns i have used correct? because i am completely from different background and having no idea. this code i picked from this portal only.

Comment: I simply tried this statement and getting nothing: for node in tree.iter('GrpHdr'):
 print(node)

Comment: I am not familiar with that library either